# Partial integration on hypersurfaces - Why is there no "boundary integral"

Tags: surfaces, weak-derivatives

In https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/C.M.Elliott/DziEll13a.pdf on page $299$ the notion of weak derivatives on hypersurfaces is introduced via

For a $2$-dimensional hypersurface $\Sigma \subset \mathbb R^3$ with unit outer normal $\eta,$ mean curvature $\mathcal H$, we call $v$ the weak gradient or $v_i \in L^1(\Sigma)$ the weak partial derivatives of $u \in L^1(\Sigma)$ if for all $\varphi \in C_0^{\infty}(\Sigma)$ we have the relation

\begin{equation}
\int_\Sigma u \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_i} \, dA = -\int_\Sigma \varphi v_i\, dA + \int_\Sigma u \varphi \mathcal H \eta_i \, dA.
\end{equation}

Now my question is: Why is the second integral not $$-\int_{\partial\Sigma} \varphi v_i\, dA?$$
Shouldn't there always be a boundary term when partially integrating?

Comment: $\varphi$ vanishes on the boundary since we demand $\varphi\in C^\infty_0(\Sigma)$.  The mean-curvature term is there when you "differentiate the $dA$".

Comment: Yes I know that it vanishes on the boundary, but my question is where the integral $-\int_{\Sigma} \varphi v_i\, dA$ comes from? Because when partially integrating , one integral should always be an evaluated on the boundary?

Comment: $v_i$ is the $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}$, so $-\int_\Sigma\varphi v_i\,\mathrm{d}A$ is the $-\int_\Sigma \varphi\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\,\mathrm{d}A$ that you would get in the usual integration by parts.

Comment: Yep I know , but why is $-\int_\Sigma \varphi v_i\, dA$ being integrated over the whole surface $\Sigma$ and not just over the boundary $\partial \Sigma$ (and I know that it would then equal zero) as one normally has when partially integrating?

Comment: the boundary term would be integrating $u\varphi$, not $\varphi v_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with Theorem 2.10 on page 297

> Assume that $\Gamma$ is a hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ with smooth boundary $\partial\Gamma$ and that $f\in C^1(\bar\Gamma)$.  Then $$\int_\Gamma\nabla_\Gamma f\,\mathrm{d}A = \int_\Gamma fH\nu\,\mathrm{d}A+\int_{\partial\Gamma}f\nu\,\mathrm{d}A.$$

So we "weaken" this and let $f=u\varphi$, $\varphi\in C^\infty_0(\Gamma)$, $u\in L^1(\Gamma)$ and we have
$$\require{color}\require{cancel}
\int_\Gamma\nabla_\Gamma (u\varphi)\,\mathrm{d}A = \int_\Gamma u\varphi H\nu\,\mathrm{d}A{\color{red}+\cancelto{0}{\int_{\partial\Gamma}u\varphi\nu\,\mathrm{d}A}}.
$$
so using Leibniz $\nabla_\Gamma(u\varphi)=(\nabla_\Gamma u)\varphi+u(\nabla_\Gamma\varphi)$ and rearrange, we have
$$
\int_\Gamma uD_i\varphi\,\mathrm{d}A = -\int_\Gamma v_i\varphi\,\mathrm{d}A+\int_\Gamma u\varphi H\nu_i\,\mathrm{d}A$$
that you see in Definition 2.11.

Comment: thank you so much, I have a monkey brain